# Create a List of random Integers using Stream and sum all elements except the smallest?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to generate 4 random numbers, ranging from 1 through 6 inclusive. Then I want to get the sum of these elements excluding the smallest value.

I am currently creating one stream to populate a list:

```
List<Integer> values =  r.ints(4,1,7).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Then I remove the smallest value and use another stream to get the sum of the values:

```
values.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Can someone suggest a way to perform all these operations in a single stream?

Answer (score 8):

[Sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted()) the stream, then [skip](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip(long)) the first (ie smallest) element:

```
int sumExceptSmallest = IntStream.of(4,1,7).sorted().skip(1).sum(); // 11
```

or in your specific case:

```
int sumExceptSmallest = r.ints(4,1,7).sorted().skip(1).sum();
```

---

Note that while this may be the coolest and most efficient for the *coder*, it is not the most efficient possible solution because the sort has [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of O(n log n). The most efficient run time would be a single pass to both find the smallest and compute the sum, then subtract one from the other, yielding the solution in O(n) time.

Answer (score 5):

Using [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) can calculate this in your stream with a single pass:

```
IntStream stream = /* random stream of integers */;
IntSummaryStatistics stats = stream.summaryStatistics();
int sum = stats.sum();
sum -= stats.min(); //sum, minus the lowest element
```